# Thread safe async method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

Let's say we have the following class:

```
    public class StreamDocumentRepresentation: DocumentRepresentation
    {
        private readonly IFileStorageService _fileStorageService;

        private readonly MemoryStream _documentStream;
        private string _fileName;

        public StreamDocumentRepresentation(MemoryStream documentStream, IFileStorageService fileStorageService)
        {
            _documentStream = documentStream;
            _fileStorageService = fileStorageService;
        }

        public override async Task<string> GetDocumentUriAsync()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_fileName))
            {
                await UploadDocument();
            }

            return _fileName;
        }

        private async Task UploadDocument()
        {
            _fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.pdf";
            await _fileStorageService.UploadFile(_fileName, _documentStream);
        }
    }
```

It represents a document as a memory stream and uploads it to file storage when we want to get a URI of the file. When we upload the file, the fileName (which is also URI) is created and stored, so when `GetDocumentUriAsync` is called a second time, it does not upload the file once more, and just returns the URI of the existing one.

The question is how to make this class thread safe to make sure, that the file will be uploaded only once?

Comment: Lock the `if` block.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay await keyword is not allowed inside lock section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is how to make this class thread safe to make sure, that the file will be uploaded only once?

You can use a `SemaphoreSlim` as a kind of async-compatible lock:

```
public class StreamDocumentRepresentation: DocumentRepresentation
{
  private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new(1);
  private readonly IFileStorageService _fileStorageService;
  private readonly MemoryStream _documentStream;
  private string _fileName;

  public override async Task<string> GetDocumentUriAsync()
  {
    await _mutex.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_fileName))
        await UploadDocument();
      return _fileName;
    }
    finally
    {
      _mutex.Release();
    }
  }

  private async Task UploadDocument()
  {
    var fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.pdf";
    await _fileStorageService.UploadFile(fileName, _documentStream);
    _fileName = fileName;
  }
}
```

Side note: I modified `UploadDocument` a bit so that it doesn't set `_fileName` if the upload fails.

Comment: I would also add `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_fileName)) return _fileName;` before the try/finally block. And, maybe, initialized the SemaphoreSlim with maxCount equals to 1.